# Argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "int *"

Tags: c++

The task

> Design a program that generates a 7-digit lottery number. The program
>   should have an INTEGER array with 7 elements. Write a loop that steps
>   through the array, randomly generating a number in the range of 0 to 9
>   for each element.Then write another loop that displays the contents of the
>   array.

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

// Global Constants
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 7;

// Declare Functions
int genNumber();
void displayResults(int lottoArray[], int ARRAY_SIZE);

// Module -- Main
int main(){
    // Declare Variables
    int LottoArray;

    // Set Functions
    LottoArray = genNumber();

    // Call Display Function
    displayResults(LottoArray, ARRAY_SIZE);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// Module -- Generate Numbers
int genNumber(){
    // Declare Variables for Array
    int lottoArray[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int i = 0;

    // Generate a Number for Each Array Placeholder
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){

        // Generate Random Number in Array
        lottoArray[i] = rand() % 10;

        int checkNumber = lottoArray[i];

        // Check for multiples
        for (int i : lottoArray){
            while (i == checkNumber){
                checkNumber = rand() % 10;
            }
        }
    }

    return lottoArray[ARRAY_SIZE];
}


// Module -- Display Results
void displayResults(int lottoArray[], int ARRAY_SIZE){
    // Declare Variables
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Lotto Numbers: ";

    // Display Each Value in the Array
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
        cout << lottoArray[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

I get the error on the title on this part of the code

```
// Call Display Function
    displayResults(LottoArray, ARRAY_SIZE);
```

I understand the problem is that I'm not returning a single int, I'm returning multiple. How would I go about fixing this? My program has to be completely modular, and the main function can only be used to call the other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues.

`genNumber` needs to return an `int *`, not an `int`, and `LottoArray` in `main` needs to be defined as `int *` as well.

Once that is fixed, you then have the problem of `genNumber` returning an array defined locally.  Once the function returns, that data becomes undefined.

Since you know how big the array is to begin with, you're probably better off passing `LottoArray` (and its size) to `genNumber` and writing to it directly, and changing the return type to `void`.

So you now have the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

// Global Constants
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 7;

// Declare Functions
void genNumber(int lottoArray[], int size);
void displayResults(int lottoArray[], int size);   // don't mask global variables

// Module -- Main
int main(){
    // Declare Variables
    int LottoArray[ARRAY_SIZE];    // define an array here

    // Set Functions
    genNumber(LottoArray, ARRAY_SIZE);

    // Call Display Function
    displayResults(LottoArray, ARRAY_SIZE);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// Module -- Generate Numbers
void genNumber(int lottoArray[], int size){
    // Declare Variables for Array
    int i = 0;

    // Generate a Number for Each Array Placeholder
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){

        // Generate Random Number in Array
        lottoArray[i] = rand() % 10;

        int checkNumber = lottoArray[i];

        // Check for multiples
        for (int i : lottoArray){
            while (i == checkNumber){
                checkNumber = rand() % 10;
            }
        }
    }
}


// Module -- Display Results
void displayResults(int lottoArray[], int size){
    // Declare Variables
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Lotto Numbers: ";

    // Display Each Value in the Array
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << lottoArray[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I kept thinking that genNumber should also pass int* but I just couldn't see how that would fix, but I was so wrong, thank you so much for the help!!